# ¿Como puedo visualizar un archivo Excel en una card y al darle click se me abra en un Modal?

Tags: modal, onclick

Quiero visualizar un archivo Excel en mi App de react en una card como la de gmail, que se vea pequeño y al hacerle click se vea grande en un Modal

No encontré algo para visualizar mi archivo Excel actualizado, y mucho menos como queria

Comment: Creo que necsitas esto https://ashishd751.github.io/excel-renderer-demo/, si estoy en lo correcto ya sabes por donde buscar, queda de ti implementar algo utilizando la [libreria](https://github.com/ashishd751/react-excel-renderer) y vuelves cuando tengas algun problema en la implementacion.

Comment: Casi olvido recordarte que tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones y corre el riesgo de ser cerrada. Como evitarlo? dale un vistazo al [tour] aprende como funciona el sitio, de paso lees [ask] y tambien debes aprender como proveer un [repro] para que tu pregunta tenga el formato adecuado y la comunidad pueda ayudarte